# Find predecessor and successor of substring in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nlp

I want to find predecessor and successor of substring in Pandas dataframe.

[image]

any idea how to do it in pandas or python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.extractall`:

```
df1 = df['Text'].str.extractall(r'(\d+)\s+([^\s]+)') \
                .droplevel(level=1) \
                .reset_index() \
                .rename(columns={0: 'values', 1: 'columns'}) \
                .astype({'values': int})
```

Intermediate result:

```
>>> df1
   index values columns
0      0     20    bats
1      0     10    cups
2      1     10    cups
3      1      5   balls
4      2      4    bags
5      2      6    cups
6      3     13    bats
7      3     14    bats
```

Now pivot and join:

```
df = df.join(df1.pivot_table(index='index', columns='columns', 
                             values='values', aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ID                                          Text  bags  balls  bats  cups
0   1            I bought 20 bats today and 10 cups     0      0    20    10
1   2                    I need 10 cups and 5 balls     0      5     0    10
2   3         I will buy 4 bags and 6 cups tomorrow     4      0     0     6
3   1  I bought 13 bats yesterday and 14 bats today     0      0    27     0
```

Regex:

- `(\d+)` find at least one or more digit
- `\s+` followed by at least one or more whitespace
- `([^\s]+)` collect everything until the next whitespace

`(...)` is a capture group.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, when I tried using the same  I am geeting the error "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape", it may be beacuse I have multiple entries for IDs, for example ID 1, can be repeated with new or old items again. how to solve this?

Comment: I think it's probably because you have same items in the same sentence. like 'I bought 20 bats yesterday and 10 bats today'. it's right? I don't think the problem is ID because I don't use it except at the end to merge/join.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I have same items in same sentence, any solution?

Comment: Thanks you very much :)

Comment: @ML_User. I updated my answer. I used `sum` function to aggregate values of a same item in the same sentence.

Comment: what if I dont have space between number and text, for example: I bought 20bats today and 10 cups

Comment: Change `\s+` to `\s*`

Comment: Hi I want to retain only numbers and required strings from the text, what should I code? for example: required strings(bags,balls,bats,cups) - data should be : first row: 1, 20 bats 10 cups second row: 2,10 cups 5 balls third row: 3, 4 bags 6 cups

Comment: `df['Text'].str.findall(r'(\d+\s+(?:bags|balls|bats|cups))').apply(' '.join)`

Comment: thank you thats cool, but if I have one more text like "I have a ball with me", then its writing blank, can get 1 with string if there is no number? – like 1 ball
ML_User
 15 hours ago    Delete

Comment: It becomes more complicated. Maybe you should use a package like [`NLTK`](https://www.nltk.org/) to parse your text rather than regex cause you need to distinguish singular and plural forms.